# Is there a way of using a row level formula to filter down to opportunities to the end of the month?

Tags: salesforce, formula, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-chatter

I am trying to use a row level formula to filter down a series of opportunities to ones which occur at the end of the month, or within 2/3 days of the end of the month.

I have the following columns: "Opp name", offer submission date, "closed date"

Purpose of the exercise: I would like to identify opportunities which have an offer submission date at the end of the month. Currently, I have filtered the report to last month.

What I would like to do: I would like to filter the data down using a row level formula, so that I have all the opportunities which have an offer submission date around the end of the last month NOT just in the last month.

Please could someone advise me as to the syntax for such a row level formula. Huge thanks in advance!

**** Edit****

This is now what my formula looks like.

[image]

And the results are:

[image]

As you can see, the records which should be highlighted as 1 (and therefore 'True') aren't. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My formula runs on Case Last Modified Date, you'll have to change field name. And mine's "DateTime" really, if your custom field is Date only - you don't need `DATEVALUE()`.

For illustration let's say anything after 20th is month's end

```
IF(DAY(DATEVALUE(LAST_UPDATE)) > 20, 1, 0)
```

[image]

Looks promising:

[image]

You can decide to make it a Text formula or maybe really just display the day of the month and filter / sort by it... Doesn't matter much, all yours?

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.
I have used the formula and adapted it into this:
```
IF(DAY((Opportunity.Bid_Submission_Deadline__c)) > 25, 1, 0)


```
However, it does not quite seem to be working correctly. It is flagging records as 0.00, which are actually within 5 days of month end.

Comment: Eyescream, please see my edit above...Thank you so much

Comment: Weird. Is "Offer submission date" and `Bid_Submission_Deadline__c` same field? Screenshot's sorted by close date but I still see some that should calculate ok. You sure you dragged the opportunity field to the report (I mean maybe you have another "Offer submission date" field on Account or Opp Line Item... What if you change the formula to just `DAY(Opportunity.Bid_Submission_Deadline__c)`? what if you temporarily make a custom field on Oppty with same formula and show that on the report?

Comment: Solved!! I had been entering "Bid_Submission_Deadline__c" rather than Offer submission date. Thank you, life saver! :)